# JQuery - I'm getting some problems using Clone()

Tags: jquery

i created a script in JQuery for tags, the script objective is when you click space, it creates automatically a new tag.

But the problem is that, i want to create a button to clone my form, and when i click at this button, it clones my form, but the tags only works for the last form, when you try to edit the tags from the first created form, you can't, because the scritpt cant recognize.

I created a jsfiddle to explain whats happening

http://jsfiddle.net/8FDjy/

I'm using this code to clone the form, and i'm using only classes

```
$(function(clone){
var template = $('.job .offer:first').clone(true);
    var offersCount = 1;
    window.addoffer = function(clone){
        offersCount++;
        var offer = template.clone(true).find(':input').each(function(){
            var newId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.length-1) + offersCount;
            this.name = this.id = newId; // update id and name (assume the same)
        }).end()
        .attr('id', 'att' + offersCount)
        .prependTo('.job');
    }
    $('.add').click(addoffer);
});
```

Comment: FYI, `live()` has been removed from jq1.9+ (referring to your jsFiddle)

Comment: Please, improve your jsFiddle with valid HTML markup. Where are these `.close` buttons???

Comment: why are you using clone parameter in the function?

Comment: Use event delegation or http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/8FDjy/1/

Answer (score 0):

live is deprecated and removed in jquery 1.8+ , use `on` delegated event for dynamically added element.

try this

```
  $('.job').on('keypress', '.txtlinks', function (e) { //Check if space was clicked, and create a new tag
 if (e.which == 32) {
     var tl = $('.txtlinks').val();
     if (tl) {
         $(this).val('').parent().before('<li class="links"><span><input type="hidden" value="' + tl + '" name="links[]" />' + tl + '</span><a style="cursor:pointer;" class="close">[x]</a></li>');


       }
   }
 });


 $('.job').on('click', '.close', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
 });


 $(function (clone) {
   var template = $('.job .offer:first').clone(true);
   var offersCount = 1;
   window.addoffer = function (clone) {
     offersCount++;
     var offer = template.clone(true).find(':input').each(function () {
         var newId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.length - 1) + offersCount;
         this.name = this.id = newId; // update id and name (assume the same)
     }).end()
         .attr('id', 'att' + offersCount)
         .prependTo('.job');
   }
  $('.add').click(addoffer);
 });
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/8FDjy/2/)